# Unity Addressable: Bundles Not Generated

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

Running `Build -> New Build -> Default Build Script` only generates `.hash` and `.json` files.

I already set `Remote` in `build & load paths`; both for the group settings and addressable asset settings. I also enabled `Build Remote Catalog` in addressable asset settings.

I only have a scene in the addressable group. I also tried having some prefabs and textures instead of just the scene but I'm still getting the same results.

I tried in addressable versions:

- 1.19.19
- 1.20.5
- 1.21.10 --> I have a different error but I believe a fix will be available in 1.21.11

Am I missing a step or maybe a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking at this, Packing and Loading paths are not set in System Settings. This defaults to Local path. If you changed the local path of the same profile to point to the Remote ones, it would probably generate the bundles next to the json and hash.

But apart from this, each group has its own "settings" under Assets/AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroups in scriptable objects called AddressableAssetGroup. These default to the global settings, unless you add override schemas to them which basically override sections of settings from the global ones. If the DefaultLocalGroup's AddressableAssetGroup contains a scheme for Content Packing & Loading, it will have a setting for the pair for Build and Load paths it will use for this bundle and this one defaults to Local.

This way the bundles always build in Library by default. But since the Remote Catalog has a separate Path pair setting, it ends up elsewhere.